# Cmd-N in Lion Finder shows "All My Files" not home?

Tags: macos, mac, finder

In Lion `Cmd-N` in Finder opens a new Window with "All My Files" showing as the default. Is it possible to set that back to the normal "home" directory of my user?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the default under `Finder` -> `Preferences`.

Look for `New Finder Window Shows`

[image: New Finder Window Shows]

Comment: I guess you posted while I was writing my answer. But given that we have identical advice, I suspect this is the right answer. :-) (Great minds think alike?)

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Select `Preferences...` from the `Finder` menu (or press <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>,</kbd>

Step 2: At `New Finder windows show`, select your home directory.

There is no step 3.

[image]